# Visual Studio wildcard search & replace in DB solution

Tags: visual-studio, wildcard

I have a database solution on VS, and I'd like to replace all occurrences of "mySchema.myTable1", "mySchema.myTable2", "mySchema.myTable3", etc. to "[mySchema].[myTable1]", "[mySchema].[myTable2]", "[mySchema].[myTable3]", etc.  Bunch of stored procedures, functions, etc. contain the table references in old format that I need to replace by the new format (with [] brackets).

Looking for Crtl + Shift + F and search/replace in entire solution via appropriate wildcard pattern.  Can you help suggest me the pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Does that works for you? Search for: `(mySchema)\.(myTable.*?)\s` and replace by `[$1].[$2] `.
Not tested a lot, I think it might fail if myTable.* is followed by a newline.